# How do I link directly to an alias through afp?

Tags: macos, afp

I'm working on an intranet web application with a file sharing server set up using AFP.

My goal is to create a link on the page that will open up Finder to a specific folder on the share network, but it has to go through an alias. I think it'd be easier to explain with an example.

For this share, there is a folder called Objects that contains a bunch of folders with unpredictable names, and a folder called Alias that contains a bunch of aliases to folders in Objects. So a link to afp://server/share/Alias/obj1 should open the folder at afp://server/share/Objects/unpredictableName, where obj1 is an alias pointing to unpredicableName.

On OSX 10.8 this works as expected, however on 10.9 and later that link opens the Finder at the Alias folder, instead of actually going into unpredictableName. What changed, and is there any way to restore the previous behavior? Thanks.

Comment: How does your code/link look which opens the Finder?

Comment: I had to set network.protocol-handler.external.afp to true in Firefox config, and the link is just <a href="afp://server/share/Alias/obj1">